# j2me to get cellid,mcc,mnc,lcc for fetching lon lat

Tags: java-me

I want to get the cellid,mcc,mnc,lac data of mobile for any device like nokia,motorola,samsung
 i had google it and able to found it for sony..But cant able to find it for samsung ,nokia,motorola.

For sony erricson device i had used the below:-

```
    String cellid = System.getProperty("com.sonyericsson.net.cellid");
    String mcc = System.getProperty("com.sonyericsson.net.cmcc");
    String mnc = System.getProperty("com.sonyericsson.net.cmnc");
    String lac = System.getProperty("com.sonyericsson.net.lac");
```

please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this article, [How to get CellId and other Imformation from mobile phones via J2ME.](http://www.easywms.com/easywms/?q=en/node/3589)

Also read this [wiki article](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/CS000947_-_Getting_Cell_ID_in_Java_ME).

Comment: thanks bhakki.i had already tried this.But i did not able to get the cell id of the device like samsung,LG.So i think bu using this it will get the cell-id of any perticular device only like sony-erricson,nokia.

Answer (score 1):

For Nokia use app called 'cellspotting'.

Nan