# how to programmatically get the mobile network code of an incoming call in android and in java me

Tags: android, blackberry, java-me

I am doing a project that requires me to get the MNC (mobile network code) of a SIM calling my phone and when I am calling a number, so that I can know which of the operators the SIM calling belongs to. I also will like to know the MNC when I am dialing a number. Please help me. It can be Android or BlackBerry or Java ME.

Answer (score 3):

In BlackBerry: [RadioInfo.getMNC(int)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/RadioInfo.html#getMNC%28int%29); but [it has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7090052/813951).

In Android: [it has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/890945/813951).

In JavaME: [it has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6213402/813951).

You could have obtained this info easily just searching in SO.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know it is not possible, since the phone has no information about dialed number. That information is available by querying MNP database, access to which is restricted to mobile network operators and other agencies registered as such.

The same may not apply to incoming calls, the information sent through GSM network to mobile phone may include MCC/MNC info, I can't remember of top of my head.